# exception handling in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, outofrangeexception

My project about networking.It gives IndexOutOfBound exception. I write try,catch block.This exception is handled but press any key to continue is message is display. give any solution.

Comment: No "solution" can be given with this information. The program exits. Why? Well, because the code "tells" it to. Perhaps there was another exception or the code comes to it's rightful end. Posting relevant code *may* lead to useful replies.

Comment: I agree with other comments: you have to give us some relevant code so we can help. But even without any code I can say, that `IndexOutOfBound` is not a kind of exception you want to handle by try-catch blocks. Your code should not throw these exceptions in the first place. Fix your array/list access logic

Answer (score 2):

You need to post code, to get a really accurate answer.  However, I'll try to help you understand what's going on.

I am guessing that you actually meant you were receiving an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, which comes with a message, "Index was outside the bounds of the array".  This means that you are trying to access an object in an array at an index, that is outside the bounds of the array.  So, if there are 2 items in an array and you try to access the third item, then you will get this exception.  New programmers get this error a lot, because they forget that arrays start at an index of 0 and not 1, so if you want to get the first item in an array you would access it like `yourArrayInstance[0]`.

Below is a simple program that causes the same exception.  Try to find something in your code that looks like it could do a similar action, and you just might find the source of your error.

```
void Main()
{
    var ary = new string[]{"hi","what's up"};
    Console.WriteLine(ary[2]);
}
```

However, you don't want to swallow the exception.  If this exception happens, it means you are doing something wrong and you need to fix it.